# Hex syntax symbol

Tags: c, hex

When i type a byte as hex:

> 0x10

Is it the same with:

> ~0x10

What is the difference?

Comment: `0x10` would mean the same as `16`.

Comment: How about learning C's operators? StackOverflow is not a "read-my-textbook" site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~0x10` gives you a bitwise not of `0x10` i.e. `0xEF`

`0x10` as binary is `00010000`.  A bitwise not of this gives you `11101111` - `0xEF` in hex

If you assigned `0x10` to a type that was larger than one byte, inverting its bits would set its least significant byte to `0xEF` and others to `0xFF`.

Comment: Except that no conforfming C implementation will have an `int` narrower than 16 bits, so this is going to give you at least `0xFFEF`.

Comment: @H2CO3 you just beat me to it, I've edited to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is a [unary bitwise complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Unary_Operator_.28.7E.29.2FOne.27s_Complement) operator. You can read all about it in 6.5.3.3 of the C spec, but in short, it's unary, because it works on one operand; and it's going to flip the bits. Additionally it performs an integer promotion on the operand.

So in your case the operand's value is 10<sub>16</sub>, which is 00010000<sub>2</sub>. Since it's only 8 bits you probably have this in a `char` type. Using the `~` operator (combined with the integer promotion) will result in 1111111111101111<sub>2</sub> (the bits were flipped).